# How to do error handling when we want array of observable to be subscribed

Tags: javascript, angular6, observable, subscription, rxjs6

I have array of Observable, Used RxJS forkJoin to capture the results emitted by each of the Observable in the array. But if any of the observable fails to emit data, the forkJoin emits no data.
So I am trying for similar behavior like forkJoin with error handling. Please do suggest any alternative that can solve the problem described above.

For work around I have created for loop for array of observable and doing error handling for each of Observable subscription. however with help of Arrow function i am able to preserve the order of the result emitted by each observable.

```
// Sample code block
const arrayOfObservable = [t,t,t,t,t];

arrayOfObservable.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.subscribe((result) => {
         // Success
    },
    (error) => {
         // Error
    },
    () => {
         // Completed
    });
});
```

Comment: I have no idea what the question is, or what a fork-join is

Comment: forkJoin - https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Comment: You cannot use forkJoin to create arrayOfObservable because it says if any fail, the forkJoin will fail. I think you would need to catch errors before/during forkJoin and turn them into 'success' somehow (maybe by returning a value)

Comment: @neaumusic- i understand the behavior of forkJoin, and I am not using forkJoin to create arrayOfObservable. Code block above what i have mentioned is workaround by using forEach to iterate through the each Observable and do error handling.

Answer (score 2):

You can use forkJoin just make sure to use catchError on inner observable so that even if an error occurs it emits all the data along with the error data.

example:

```
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { forkJoin, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';

forkJoin(
    ajax.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users/google'),
    ajax.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users/microsoft'),
    /* this throws an error */
    ajax.getJSON('https://api.github.com/uses').pipe(catchError(error => of(error))),
)
// [object,  object,  Error ]
.subscribe(console.log);
```

link to the working example of the same : https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-czentk

Comment: Thank you, will give a try with the code mentioned above. and the link you have mentioned is not opening.